# Why each word is in a separate line?

Tags: html, css, inline, text-styling

I have a problem, it is weird, I thought I have finished a task but I was playing with the browser and then boom, a problem, so I have a container with flex displaying, it contains links elements, each element has a text, but now, the text is not displayed correctly, I don't know why, is it because of flex displaying of the parent ? I don't know, here is what I want to achieve :

[image]

But that is what I get :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[image]

I don't get that return, why is that ?

Here is my html code :

```
    <div class="header__options">
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(0)">
            Dernières minutes
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(1)">
            Vol
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(2)">
            Séjour
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(3)">
            Location
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(4)">
            Camping
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(5)">
            Hôtel
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(6)">
            Train
        </a>
    </div>
```

And my css :

```
.header__options a {

    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;

    font-size: 14px;

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What behavior did you expect? It's not clear what you're asking, especially since you haven't shown all the relevant CSS. Please fix your image markdown.

Comment: Well two people answered, and they are correct, it worked, so tehy understood the question, and answered correclty, so I think Sir it is clear what I am asking

Comment: Since all text wraps by default, it's not. Also, the question of how to prevent text from wrapping has been answered hundreds of times, so it's odd that you didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `white-space: nowrap` will ensure that the element text does not wrap, and stays on one line.

```css
.header__options {
  background: black;
}
.header__options a {
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  
  /* Add white-space: nowrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__options">
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(0)">
        Dernières minutes
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(1)">
        Vol
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(2)">
        Séjour
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(3)">
        Location
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(4)">
        Camping
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(5)">
        Hôtel
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDetails(6)">
        Train
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_white-space